# Is the launcher included in a native JavaFX bundle freshly compiled or just copied?

Tags: java, c++, linux, javafx, packaging

I have difficulties understanding what happens during execution of the JavaFX Packager on Linux.

The executable launcher, that is added to a self-contained application package is apparently compiled from [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/fe6b492b9150/modules/fxpackager/src/main/native/launcher/linux/launcher.cpp) c++ file.

However I was unable to find this file in an installation of the *Oracle* JDK 8u92 (please note that the above file is from the OpenJFX project). I assume that JavaFX bundled with Oracle's JDK works similar or is the same.

As there is a bug in the above .cpp file, I want to exchange it before running the JavaFX Packager.

Q1: Is there any chance to replace the launcher source?

Q2: Is the launcher even really compiled from source or is there a pre-compiled launcher shipped with the JDK, that is just renamed and put into the package?

Q3: If it gets compiled, is there a chance that different gcc versions or flags influence whether `new char[MAX_PATH]` is pre-initialized to `\0` and not just allocated?